# How to extract string within these tags?

Tags: android, regex, replace

I've got the following string

```
String text = "<div align="center"><a href="http://www.ndtv.com/news/images/topstory_thumbnail/  Shatrughan_Sinha_agency_120.jpg"><img border="0" src="http://www.ndtv.com/news/images/topstory_thumbnail/Shatrughan_Sinha_agency_120.jpg" alt="2013-07-29-08-43-05" /></a></div><p><span style="font-size: large;">The BJP is likely to anoint Narendra Modi as its prime ministerial candidate for the 2014 elections and make a formal announcement to that effect by September.</span><br /><br /><span style="font-size: large;"> A day after Narendra Modi appeared to declare himself his party's prime ministerial candidate, another initiative by him has not been welcomed by the BJP's Bihar branch.  </span><br /><br /><span style="font-size: large;">BJP President Rajnath Singh today appeared to bat for Gujrat Chief Minister Narendra Modi as the party's Prime Ministerial candidate and said it is now Congress' turn to make clear its choice of its candidate for the top post.    </span><br /><br /></p>";
```

How do I remove the foll string from the above string text?

```
<div align="center"><a href="http://www.ndtv.com/news/images/topstory_thumbnail/  Shatrughan_Sinha_agency_120.jpg"><img border="0" src="http://www.ndtv.com/news/images/topstory_thumbnail/Shatrughan_Sinha_agency_120.jpg" alt="2013-07-29-08-43-05" /></a></div>
```

Comment: WHAT YOU WANT TO EXTRACT FROM GIVEN TEXT ?

Comment: simply make a substring till first "</div>" and remove it. Or take the right part.

Comment: foll string? what do oyu mean by foll?